# Partial Least Squares Regression for categorical factor

Tags: r, partial, least-squares

I adjust the Partial Least Squares Regression for one categorical factor (2 levels – be or not to be) with with the pls package in R. I try to use round() function in the predict values for take the decision if the result are the first or second level in my factor, this approach sounds correct?

```
require(pls)
```

## Artificial data

```
T<-as.factor(sort(rep(c("be", "nottobe"), 100))) 

y1 <- c(rnorm(100,1,0.1),rnorm(100,1,0.1)) 

y2 <- c(rnorm(100,10,0.3),rnorm(100,10,0.6)) 
y3 <- c(rnorm(100,10,2.3),rnorm(100,11,2.6)) 
y4 <- c(rnorm(100,5,0.5),rnorm(100,7,0.5)) 
y5 <- c(rnorm(100,0,0.1),rnorm(100,0,0.1))
```

## Create the data frame

```
avaliacao <- as.numeric(T) 
espectro <- cbind(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5) 
dados <- data.frame(avaliacao = I(as.matrix(avaliacao)), bands = I(as.matrix(espectro)))
```

## PLS regression

```
taumato <- plsr(avaliacao ~ bands, ncomp = 5, validation = "LOO", data=dados) 
summary(taumato)
```

## Components analysis

```
plot(taumato, plottype = "scores", comps = 1:5)
```

## Cross validation

```
taumato.cv <- crossval(taumato, segments = 10) 
plot(MSEP(taumato.cv), legendpos = "topright") 
summary(taumato.cv, what = "validation") 
plot(taumato, xlab ="medição", ylab="predição", ncomp = 3, asp = 1, main=" ", line = TRUE)
```

## Predition for 3 components

```
T<-as.factor(sort(rep(c("be", "nottobe"), 50))) 

y1 <- c(rnorm(100,1,0.1),rnorm(100,1,0.1)) 
y2 <- c(rnorm(100,10,0.3),rnorm(100,10,0.6)) 
y3 <- c(rnorm(100,10,2.3),rnorm(100,11,2.6)) 
y4 <- c(rnorm(100,5,0.5),rnorm(100,7,0.5)) 
y5 <- c(rnorm(100,0,0.1),rnorm(100,0,0.1)) 

espectro2 <- cbind(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5) 
new.dados <- data.frame(bands = I(as.matrix(espectro2))) 
round(predict(taumato, ncomp = 3, newdata = new.dados))##
```